# Efficiently evaluate the mean of different simulations in columns

Tags: r, simulation, multiple-columns, mean, median

I want to evaluate the mean() and median() of data derived from different simulations. Let's say that I have a matrix like the one below, where `Run` represents the different runs.

I need to evaluate the mean for the `Value 1` and `Value 2` evaluated over the different runs during the time.

```
Time Run Value1  value 2
 1    0   2.5       3
 2    0    4       2.3
 3    0    2        1 
 4    0    2        4
 1    1    4        2
 2    1    2        5
 3    1    2        3.7
 1    2    4        2
 2    2   3.5       3
```

Comment: PLease show some effort (functions & code used) before asking basic questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would like to take the mean of (2.5, 4, 2, 2) for value 1 for run 0, the mean of (4, 2, 2) for value 1 for run 1, etc., you can do

```
meansVal1   <- vector()
meansVal2   <- vector()
mediansVal1 <- vector()
mediansVal2 <- vector()

for (r in 0:max(m[,2])) {

  meansVal1[r+1]   <-   mean(m[,3][m[,2] == r])
  meansVal2[r+1]   <-   mean(m[,4][m[,2] == r])
  mediansVal1[r+1] <- median(m[,3][m[,2] == r])
  mediansVal2[r+1] <- median(m[,4][m[,2] == r])

}
```